# passing data from view to controller using a form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been reading rails documents and guides all day and trying out different tutorials all day but nothing seems to help. I currently have a small app which has a stop table, a bus table and a schedule table. The schedule table is a rich join between bus and stop table. I understand the db and model part of rails clearly compared to the controllers and views.

My stop table has a id field, a longitude field, and a latitude field.

I basically want user to input a value for longitude and latitude and then do a query and find out the stop id by matching the user given longitude and latitude in the stop table.

What is the best way to achieve this? In my opinion i can create a form which will let user enter longitude and latitude and i can store that value in some variable and then do a query. I know exactly what i want to do but i don't know how to do it in rails. I am very frustrated and i would appreciate any input.

My code for form in index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :welcome do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :longitude %><br>

    <%= f.text_field :longitude %>
    <br>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :latitude %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :latitude %>


  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

My code for controller

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
     @long = params[:longitude]
     @lat =  params[:latitude]
  end


end
```

Please inform me if i am doing something wrong? Also how do i proceed from here onwards? I would really appreciate any help i have been stuck at this same point for the past 8 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure you model is represented in the database, have you run a migration, can you post your schema?

If you are starting from scratch, you could run this command to get up and running quickly with the model:

```
bin/rails generate model Location latitude:string longitude:string

bin/rake db:migrate
```

UPDATE: If you don't need the user Location to persist in the database, you can use [ActiveModel](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) (skip the above). In the models folder create a location.rb file and create the ActiveModel:

```
class Location
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :latitude, :longitude
end
```

Now that Location model is in place, you'll need to save the latitude and longitude using a create method in the controller:

```
def create
  @location= Location.new(params[:location])

  @location.save
  redirect_to @location
end
```

UPDATE: now that you've captured the user location, you want to use this information to compare it to your Stop table in order to find the record that is relevant. Here, you'll want to do this work using resque (or other queue) or by making a call to a third-party API like Google maps for example, or use whatever algorithm you've come up with.

You also want to make sure that you have routes, the default CRUD routes can be achieved by:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :location
end
```

finally in your view (note I'm using the model name location instead of welcome):

```
<%= form_for :location do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :latitude %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :latitude %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :longitude %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :longitude %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to create a separate table called Location ? The reason i am asking is because i have a stop table containing name,longitude and latitude of different bus stops. So when a user enters longitude and latitude i simply map them to a bus stop from the stop table. So in such a case i would need to only temporarily hold the longitude and latitude value received from the user. As such why would i make a new table called location? Sorry i dont mean to criticize you you are probably right but i just want to understand the reasoning.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean the bus stops are pre-populated, you wouldn't need a database table for the user input unless you wanted to log it in the database, if not you could use something called [active_model](http://www.rubyinside.com/rails-3-0s-activemodel-how-to-give-ruby-classes-some-activerecord-magic-2937.html)

Comment: Sorry i was not clear in my question. But basically i will have pre populated Table called Stop which will have name,longitude and latitude. So now when a user enters a longitude and latitude i will assign them a stop id based on the match.  So thats why i was thinking of taking in user inputs , temporarily storing them in a variable and then doing a query in stop table where longitude = @ long and latitude = @ lat and if both match i would return a stop id. I would highly appreciate if you can show me how to do this. I know once i get over the basic learning curve i can accelerate.

Comment: I will definitely upvote and accept your answer. thanks again for your input thus far. i have been just trying badly to achieve this all day but no luck so far.

Comment: Is it  possible for you to show how to store users input temporarily so I can use them to compare ? I tried all night still no luck

Answer (score 1):

If you want something with a little bit more features, you should try [geokit-rails gem](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails), this will let you query stops by coordinates, and get results even if the coordinates aren't exactly, right, it will fetch the closest stops.

- First check the gem page and check how to install the gem.
- Then add the `mappable` command in your stop model

  ```
  class Stop < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_mappable
  end
  ```

  **note:** check [the options](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails#making-a-model-mappable) for `acts_as_mappable` cause you'll need to change some stuff, like default distance unit and default `lat` and `lng` column names
- Then now you could do a query in your controller like this

  ```
  class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
      lng = params[:longitude]
      lat =  params[:latitude]
      Stop.within(5, origin: [lat, lng]
    end
  end
  ```

  This will find all the bus stops that are within 5 miles (which is the default distance unit, can be changed to km) from the point you provided in the search

**note**: The params will probably be scoped inside a `:welcome` key, so it might be better to whitelist them using strong parameters

```
def bus_stop_params
  params.require(:welcome).permit(:latitude, :longitude)
end
```

Comment: I will look in to your suggestion. But for time being , is it possible to show me how i can tweak my solution to achieve the desired result...Thanks again i will definitely look in to it but i was very much stuck as to how to pass value from view to controller as i will need to know this for the future for many cases. so if you can please help me there i would appreciate it.

Comment: the thing is that the params are under `:location`, so to access them you'll need to do something like this `@longitude = params[:location][:longitude]`

Comment: When i do params[:location][:longitude] i get an error saying undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: well you need to inspect your `params` then, if you know how to use a debugger then debug and check the `params`, if not try doing `puts params.inspect` and check the value in the log

Answer (score 0):

If I can suggest something: watch this Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder?view=asciicast

This will help you achieve what you are looking for it a simpler manner than the route you currently are going down.

Basically what this episode entails is how to use a gem to convert place names to coordinates and vice-versa and even convert IP addresses to street addresses. The Geocoder gem can also find nearby locations with their distance and bearing and has many other useful features.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion , I will look at that link right after i type this comment. Also if you can suggest a solution for my above situation i would appreciate as i know there are better ways of doing this but i feel if you help me with my situation it will help me understand how values are passed between view and controller and vice versa which i feel is extremely important to understand rails framework. I will definitely look at the link you posted now. Thanks again